# Fixed Row on scroll is overlapping other rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm wanting to make a fixed row inside a container and it's giving me some problems where it's overlapping the divs below.

Before the fixed row:
[image]

After a fixed row:
[image]

What would be the proper way to handle this? I've tried messing with child classes and setting the container as relative and no luck at all.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.css"/>

<style>

.heading {
    background-color: #00C6D7;
}
.sub-heading {
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}
.container {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(77,72,69,0.2), 0 6px 10px rgba(77,72,69,0.15);
}
.col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-12 {
    padding-top: .6rem!important;
    padding-bottom: .6rem!important;
}
.col-xs-3 {
    word-break: break-word;
}
.bl {
    border-left: 1px solid lightgray;
}
.bb {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #00C6D7;
}
.bg-white {
    background-color: white;
}
.mainText {
    font-style: italic;
    color: #00C6D7;
}
.bg-fhdark {
    background-color: #5E6A71;
}
.title {
    color: #A2AD00;
}

/* Slick Carousel */
@media (max-width: 450px) {
    .slick-next {
        right: 0px!important;
    }
}
.slick-next {
    right: 15px;
}
.slick-prev:before {
  color: #5E6A71;
}
.slick-next:before {
  color: #5E6A71;
}
.no-arrows > .slick-next,
.no-arrows > .slick-prev {
   display: none!important;
}
/* ----- */

/* BootStrap 4 Classes */
.py-5 {
    padding-bottom: 3rem!important;
    padding-top: 3rem!important;
}
.py-2 {
    padding-bottom: .5rem!important;
    padding-top: .5rem!important;
}
.text-white {
    color: #fff!important;
}
.text-left {
    text-align: left!important;
}
.text-uppercase {
    text-transform: uppercase!important;
}
.font-weight-bold {
    font-weight: 700!important;
}
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row-11 {
    height: auto!important;
}
ul {
    padding-left: 0px;
}
/* ----- */
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row heading">
            <div class="col-xs-9 text-white text-left py-2">
                <h4 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Performance Benchmark</h4>
                <p>Our goal is to develop a set of expectations that are consistent across the 
                    agency and reflect growth as a priority. Some expectations, such as 
                    negotiating, listening and interpersonal communication are not included 
                    but are considered baseline skills to perform your role. 
                    The Performance Benchmark consists of four main areas: 
                    Client, Talent, Business Development & Growth, and Finance & Operations. 
                    Each area is outlined at the Junior, Mid and Senior Levels.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 text-center" style="margin: auto;">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <section class="regular slider">
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <h6 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold title">Junior</h6>
                        <span>Valued Colleague and Practitioner</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <h6 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold title">Mid</h6>
                        <span>Trusted Colleague; Proven and Creative Practitioner</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <h6 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold title">Senior</h6>
                        <span>Trusted Client Advisor and Partner; Proven Agency Leader</span>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
        
                <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 bg-fhdark">
                <span class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-white">Client</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row bb">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <span>Client Focus, Strategic Counsel and Consultancy</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <section class="regular slider no-arrows">
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Develops understanding of clients' business and goals</li>
                            <li>Beings to understand agency's solutions for clients and how they drive business results</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Understands clients' business needs and contributes to building strong client relationships</li>
                            <li>Develops programs and solutions that effectively meet business needs and priorities</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Anticipates clients' business and communications needs</li>
                            <li>Is responsive, results-oriented and growth-focused</li>
                            <li>Counsels clients on capabilities, products and services that will deliver greatest value to their business</li>
                            <li>Is conversant in full range of communications practices and disciplines</li>
                            <li>Is able to have tough client conversations</li>
                            <li>Inspires clients' confidence in agency and account team</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".regular").slick({
        dots: false,
        infinite: false,
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        asNavFor: '.slider',
        responsive: [
            {
            breakpoint: 600,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1
                }
            }]
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Your code seems to show the "Before the fixed row" version, can you show us what youre doing to make that row fixed?

Comment: When `position: fixed` is used the element is removed from the normal document flow. To solve this you need to compensate for the heading's height by adding `margin-top` to the next sibling (your second `.row`) or `padding-top` to the body. You can use js to find the right value or just simply set `.heading` to a fixed height.

Comment: @GiorgioZanni, I've tied this but it's still giving me errors and not doing much.

Comment: Everything Giorgio stated is correct. Also, consider adding "z-index: 1" to the fixed element in case overlap happens at least it looks nicer. For a responsive design, you'd want that padding or margin to change as the height of your fixed element changes. You can do this in a clunky way with a ton of media breakpoints in CSS, or as Giorgio stated, using JS to listen for changes to viewport dimensions, measuring the height of the fixed element and applying that to the padding or margin. However, this has a downside of some weird scrolling effects in some mobile browsers (e.g. iOS).